# Iterate over pairs of variables in for loop in Python to reduce code redundancy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have 3 separate dicts: df1, df2 and df3 with the same column names. I am trying to merge each unique pair of dicts, count the length of the merged dicts and save each length in a dict. How can I do this in a for loop?

```
final_dict = {}

df1 = {}
df2 = {}
df3 = {}

df1_df2 = df1.merge(df2, on = ["column_name1, column_name2, column_name3"])
df1_df3 = df1.merge(df3, on = ["column_name1, column_name2, column_name3"])
df2_df3 = df2.merge(df3, on = ["column_name1, column_name2, column_name3"])

length1 = len(df1_df2)
length2 = len(df1_df3)
length3 = len(df2_df3)
```

I'd like to have key,value pairs in final_dict to have:

```
'df1_df2': length1
'df1_df3': length2
'df2_df3': length3
```

Since I'm doing the same merge and length operations on different pairs of dicts, can I efficiently do this in a for loop to reduce code redundancy?

Comment: Create a function that takes two parameters (left df and right df) for a merge operation within it. Then you can return its length. Then you can use a for loop to pass a list of tuples containing the dictionaries you want to merge, adding the return of the function as the value to the key. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations

dict_ls = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3}
cols = ["column_name1", "column_name2", "column_name3"]

final_dict = {}

for l, r in list(combinations(dict_ls, 2)):
    df_merged = dict_ls[l].merge(dict_ls[r], on=cols)
    final_dict[l+'_'+r] = len(df_merged)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
for i in range(len(dfs) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(dfs)):
        key = f'df{i + 1}_df{j + 1}'
        merged = dfs[i].merge(dfs[j], on=['column_name1', 'column_name2', 'column_name3'])
        final_dict[key] = len(merged)
```